# Recovering from removal of ibdata1

Tags: mysql, innodb, ibdata

I just upgraded from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy and `mysql` stopped working. Blindly following [some advice](https://serverfault.com/a/509413) without any understanding of what I was doing, I removed `ibdata1` in an attempt to solve the problem. Unfortunately, it was only after doing so that I realised this was a terrible idea, especially as I was **missing this option** in `my.cnf`: `innodb_file_per_table = 1`.

I found the cause of my problem and now my DB server is working again. However, now, I am left with a mess. My problem is that some (but not all) of my tables, which appear when I do `show tables;`, are giving me this error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.tablename' doesn't exist
```

I have since enabled the setting `innodb_file_per_table = 1` (perhaps this was a bad idea?) and before I came to realise that I probably didn't have a chance, I was trying out the `innodb_force_recovery` flags.

I'm fairly confident that these tables are gone for good so I'm trying to restore my database from earlier dumps. The problem is that the import breaks on these tables that "*do but don't*" exist. I have tried dropping the database before doing the import but there are clearly some other files lying around. Needless to say I'm reluctant to do any more speculative deletion of files...

Any advice on how to clean up this mess?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Actually,I don't think it is a duplicate because when `ibdata1` was removed, I don't think I had any `.ibd` files due to my settings. I have since recovered the tables from backup so my problem is solved. Nevertheless, your answer to the other question looks useful, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

THere are three ways to recover your tables:

1. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/05/13/connecting-orphaned-ibd-files/
2. http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28
3. Extract records from the ibd files with page_parser/constraints_parser from [Data Recovery Toolkit](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)

**UPDATE**: Data recovery toolkit moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any .ibd files due to my settings at the time of deletion

Comment: omg, i misread your Q.
Okay, then skip to #3. umount partition where ibdata1 was or stop all writes. Then scan the partiton with page_parser and then fetch recrods with constraints_parser

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go but I think it's probably too late as the blunder was committed two days ago now.

Comment: of course, the sooner your stop writes the bigger chance to get your data back. Still I'd give a try page_parser. All it finds is recoverable, so it can give you an idea if it's worth efforts